# Equivalence of cvMatchTemplate() in BoofCV or pure java computer vision library?

Tags: java, computer-vision, boofcv

I am looking for solutions [BoofCV](http://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) or any pure java computer vision library that doesn't require OpenCV to do template matching of images to detect object within a picture.

For example, finding the position of an image within a bigger picture.

I have had success with `cvMatchTemplate()` example on `OpenCV`, but interested in using `BoofCV` to achieve the same results.

Comment: It wouldn't take long to add that functionality to BoofCV.  However, template matching is slow and very sensitive to noise...  I'll add that functionality to BoofCV is you do the following:

1) Provide an interesting example image and template that you wish to be searched through that I can use in an example on the website.
2) What problem do you hope to solve with this functionality?

Either e-mail me those answers or post them to BoofCV's mailing list.  Both can be found easily.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you I will send out an email or post on the mailing list this weekend!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality has recently been added to BoofCV.  See example below:

http://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Example_Template_Matching

Comment: the code doesn't compile due to missing ImageStatistics class

Comment: The examples were linking to the latest GIT code and not the stable release.  Download the code and go to the examples directory.  For tech support type questions please send a private message or post to the message board.

Comment: yes. I've done that and it's working but it's extremely slow! I've used SimpleCV and it was done in a fraction of  time while BoofCV took 10+ seconds to complete.

Comment: If the algorithms are identical and implemented equally well I would expected Java to be about 3 times slow in this case.  Array heavy operations take the biggest hit.

Comment: well...it was worth a shot.

Comment: @PeterAbeles what are `templatePaint` and `templateBrowser` what shall I give as input for these variables? I think only a Source image and template image are enough but I dont understand the other 2 also where shall I specify a value for `expectedMatches` ?

Comment: Those are just templates for paint and browser icons.  It does a search for three different templates.  Those two plus the "X"

Answer (score 2):

It seems this functionality is not implemented in BoofCV.

Comment: Any pure Java computer vision library solution that doesn't depend on opencv?